# Why do my villagers run towards zombies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a villager trading hall which uses the ai of villagers to move them along. A zombie will make them run until they fall into a hole. I finished the project and threw a villager in there, and it ran towards the zombie and died. So did all of the other attempts. I can’t figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Villagers always attempt to get back to their village once they get too far away. My guess is that you transported the villager away from the village and that it is now trying to get back there by itself and thus run into the arms of the zombie.

In order to solve this, you should either build your village on the other side of the contraption, causing the villager to run towards the correct side instead, or move the village even further away, so that the villager can't "see" it anymore.
Another option would be to not rely on AI, but then you'd need to rebuild your entire setup, which might not be desirable.

EDIT:
Using your description, I performed my own test. This is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, all the villagers ran away from the zombie as expected. Next I built a village a few blocks behind the zombie, to "lure" the villagers towards the zombie:

[image]

As you can see, all the villagers are now moving towards the zombie instead, trying to get to the village.

Comment: Dont villagers forget their village if moved far enough away?

Comment: Also I tested it another world and they run towards the zombies even without a village

Comment: @CarterRay Villagers do forget their village if they are far enough away, but far enough away is over 64 blocks if I'm not mistaken. I'd like to see your test setup so that I can have better insight in how you performed your tests.

Comment: Test setup is just a zombie trapped with trap doors and a slab on top. The floor is trapped doors (required for this trading hall) and the villagers can only go one way because the rest is blocked off using a tube made of slabs.

Comment: and you are 100% certain that there are no wooden doors nearby? not even for your own use? and there are no free roaming villagers anywhere? and there are no villages far away that somehow have merged into a big village that has an expanded border?

Comment: There are free roaming villagers.

Comment: you may want to check that those free roaming villagers can't reach any wooden doors that are not intended to be part of the village. You might find that those free villagers unintentially create new villages and these villages might merge together, making a complete mess of all your villages.

Comment: I did this in a blank testing world with 0 doors in it.

Comment: @CarterRay I added an example to my answer to explain my words.

Comment: So I’ll have to move my trading hall far away

Comment: Yes, either that or your villager breeder. They should be over 64 blocks apart if I remember correctly.